# Netsuite REST API for cross-subsidiary item fulfillment

Tags: rest, netsuite

I get the following error when I call the item fulfillment Netsuite rest api.

```
Error while accessing a resource. You must have at least one valid line item for this transaction.
```

The sales order needs to be fulfilled with an item that is available in another subsidiary. This can be done in UI but I have not been able to achieve that using the rest call as described from the following help site:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_161425629582.html

The following is the JSON I am using:

```
    {
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "orderLine": 1,
                "quantity": 1,
                "itemReceive": true,
                "location": {
                    "id": "239"
                },
                "inventoryDetail": {
                    "inventoryassignment": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "issueInventoryNumber": {
                                    "refName": "1D3B62A4000070"
                                },
                                "quantity": 1.0
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "quantity": 1.0,
                    "totalResults": 1
                },
                "shipGroup" : 1,
                "subsidiary": {
                    "id": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "subsidiary": {
        "id": "1"
    },
    "location": {
        "id": "239"
    }
}
```

The location 239 belongs in subsidiary 1 while the order is placed in subsidiary 3.

Is it possible to use Netsuite rest api to fulfill orders with items from another subsidiary (cross-subsidiary fulfillment)? If yes, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed up with Netsuite support and they confirmed that cross-subsidiary fulfillment is not currently supported via Netsuite REST web services. The workaround is to build a restlet which then can be called to do cross-sub fulfillment.

Answer (score 0):

Is it due to role permission if the same action can be done thru UI ? Your API need to execute either using administrator role or a custom role that has access to multiple subsidiaries (at least the subsidiaries that you testing).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was using admin in UAT so that is not the reason it does not work. The cross-sub is not currently supported via native rest services in Netsuite. We will build a restlet to do this.